# dynamically changing color of button issue

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I am trying to change the button color from programming ,
if there is only one button code works fine ,but if there are four buttons , more than one changes color

In my code ,i am randomly selecting a button out of four and changing its color,
but actually,more than one change color ,sometimes 2,sometimes 3 ,sometimes all of them(they are changing color at same time but i want them to change color one by one).

following is my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
    Random r = new Random();
    int random_selection;
    Thread t1;
int i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);


 main();


    }

    public void main() {

        Handler handler1 = new Handler();

            handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int count = 0;
                    try {
                        System.out.println("inside run");
                        for (i = 0;i<4 ;i++ ) {

                             Handler handler2 = new Handler();
                            int x = randomgen();

                            if (x == 1) {
                                b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        b1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);


                            } else if (x == 2) {
                                b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        b2.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);


                            } else if (x == 3) {
                                b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        b3.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);


                            } else if (x == 4) {
                                b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        b4.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);


                            }


                        }
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("inside catch");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, 1000 );


    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a Handler? They only make this program much more complicated than necessary without any appreciable benefit.

Comment: You should also use an array so that you do not need any if statements. Names like b1, b2, etc. almost always indicate the need for an array.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice cause in android i cannot do user interface functions on main thread , so i have use a different thread

Comment: You never start a new thread here. All of your code runs on the main thread despite what you think.

Answer (score 1):

You do that four times:

```
for (i = 0;i<4 ;i++ ) { ... }
```

So no wonder, up to 4 buttons will change color. It is sometimes less because sometimes you will get the same random number more than once.

Comment: may be i have not explained well,but multiple buttons are getting black at same ,but i want them to get black one by one in random manner,for loop is there to ensure that this happens 4 times only

Comment: then you want to 1) shuffle the buttons rather than select 4 times a random one and 2) put a delay between each button's color change.